# Converting object into array using only jq and bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a JSON formatted stream, full of objects. Each object looks like this:

```
{
  "object": "alpha",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "description": "a",
      "value": 1271129046.9144535
    },
    {
      "type": "B",
      "description": "b",
      "value": 6738889338.63777
    },
    {
      "type": "C",
      "description": "c",
      "value": 214918692.38456276
    },
    {
      "type": "D",
      "description": "d",
      "value": 140222346.75136077
    },
    {
      "type": "E",
      "description": "e",
      "value": 2085635554.8128803
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to get data out as:

```
alpha,A,a,1271129046.9144535
alpha,B,b,6738889338.63777
alpha,C,c,214918692.38456276
alpha,D,d,140222346.75136077
alpha,E,e,2085635554.8128803
```

The next object may be "beta" instead of "alpha", hence I don't want to just strip the "object" key.

My restrictions are that I want to process this stream in a bash pipeline. I'm hoping I can just use "jq" for this, rather than piping through python/ruby/perl etc which I'd rather not depend on if I can help it.

Any ideas would be most grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're building up CSV data, the `@csv` filter was made for this.  You just need to collect an array of the values you want to write out and pass it in to the filter.  You could do this:

```
$ jq -r '.attributes[] as $attr | [.object, $attr.type, $attr.description, $attr.value] | @csv' input.json
```

Which produces this:

```
"alpha","A","a",1271129046.9144535
"alpha","B","b",6738889338.63777
"alpha","C","c",214918692.38456276
"alpha","D","d",140222346.75136077
"alpha","E","e",2085635554.8128803
```

Comment: Yet another feature I wasn't aware of in jq! It's a veritable smorgasbord of utility!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Slightly briefer than the accepted answer:

```
jq -r '[.object] + (.attributes[] | [.type, .description, .value]) | @csv'
```

(2) If you don't want the quotation marks, then one possibility would be:

```
jq -r '"\(.object)," + (.attributes[] | "\(.type),\(.description),\(.value)")'
```